# Is there a way to re-enable the Mac OS X dashboard?

Tags: macos, dashboard

Is there a way to re-enable the Mac OS X dashboard?  I used to play tons of games that take tons of RAM, so I decided to turn off the dashboard, but now that I only play games that don't require a lot of ram RAM I would like to re-enable the dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you did this via the command line you ran a command like this to disable the Dashboard:

```
defaults write com.apple.dashboard mcx-disabled -bool TRUE && killall Dock
```

So to reenable it just run the same command but substitute `FALSE` for `TRUE` like this:

```
defaults write com.apple.dashboard mcx-disabled -bool FALSE && killall Dock
```

Answer (score 0):

System Prefs > Mission Control > Dashboard - set to Overlay or Space

[image]

Comment: Woah!  I thought I would have to have a ten line long terminal command.  Thanks!