# Is “YES/NO” or “TRUE/FALSE” preferred when using “defaults write” in Mac OS X? Or does it just not matter at all?

Tags: macos, mac

I just [posted the following answer](https://superuser.com/a/1037214/167207) to [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1037212/167207) and stumbled across something that confuses me: When setting the value of a `defaults write` setting via the Terminal in Mac OS X, is a `YES`/`NO` or a `true`/`false` setting preferred? Or does it just not matter and Mac OS X can accept `YES`/`NO` or a `TRUE`/`FALSE` without issue?

These two commands in Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) seem to work the same:

```
defaults write com.apple.dashboard mcx-disabled -bool TRUE && killall Dock
defaults write com.apple.dashboard mcx-disabled -bool YES && killall Dock
```

Ditto with these two commands that undo the values that those other commands set:

```
defaults write com.apple.dashboard mcx-disabled -bool FALSE && killall Dock
defaults write com.apple.dashboard mcx-disabled -bool NO && killall Dock
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/defaults.1.html) for defaults:

```
 -bool[ean]  Allows the user to specify a boolean as the value for the given preference key.  Value must
             be TRUE, FALSE, YES, or NO.
```

It would appear they've simply built in recognition for both YES/TRUE and NO/FALSE, and neither is preferable. They'll likely be translated to a 0 or 1 in the end anyway.

Comment: They're translated to ‘true’/‘false’ in the plist which `defaults read` returns ‘1’/‘0’ for.